# Psychonauts on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: steam, windows-7, psychonauts

Anyone have any luck getting this to run on Windows 7 64-bit?

I grabbed the demo on Steam, and it won't run; so I am hesitant to buy actual title until i know the demo can run.

Comment: "Won't run" how?

Comment: The one I bought from Steam works fine on my Win7 64-bit rig. I think you'll need to delve a bit further than the OS to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: I fire it up, and it just doesn't load.  I tried various combinations of 'Run in Adminstirator Mode', 'Compatibility Mode', Turning of dual monitor support,etc.  Nothing.  It shows up in my Windows Application Error Log that the .exe failed to launch ... but not much more details than that.

Comment: I have the full version on Steam and it runs fine. Have you tried things such as disabling the Steam overlay and checking the Steam forums to see if anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Steam version runs fine, even though the demo did not work.  I got the copy via the Humble Bundle V.

So, don't let the demo fool you, the game works fine on Windows 7, 64bit.

Answer (score 3):

I bought it from GOG.com and run it on Windows 7 64bit just fine. I am not sure if it works any differently with Steam, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you do decide to buy it, buy it from GOG.  GOG modifies the game for you so it runs on modern hardware.  Another benefit of it is that they give you a DRM free copy.
The only other recommendation I can give is trying to play it in compatibility mode.